# AngularJS route change happens before ng-leave animation is finished

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I am using the following css code, to animate my ui-view changes.

```
.fadein.ng-enter,
.fadeout.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 1s;
  -o-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
  display: block !important;
}

.fadein.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadeout.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadein.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  transition-delay: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadeout.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

and here it gets applied to the ngview:

```
 <div ui-view class="fadein fadeout"></div>
```

However, the route change (initiated by $state.go("home.dashboard") for example) always happens, before my ng-leave animation even started (the fadeout animation).

I tried adding the
    transition-delay: 1s; 
attribute, but the animation still is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but adding

```
position: absolute;
```

to my ui-view div solved the issue.